# Failed to connect to the database: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC" : SET time zone 'UTC'

Tags: postgresql, psql, archlinux, metasploit

While trying to run metasploit in arch linux im getting

```
[root@archserver ~]# msfconsole
[-] Failed to connect to the database:
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter
"TimeZone": "UTC" : SET time zone 'UTC'
```

Postgres configuration is done and db is also created

My database.yml is

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: msf
 username: root
 password: root
 host: localhost
 port: 5432
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by editing SET time zone 'UTC' in `/opt/metasploit/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb`

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you have multiple postgres instances running. This happened when I installed `postgres@9.4` via homebrew then later uninstalled and installed an updated version of postgres. What I failed to realize was, `postgres@9.4` was still running in the background

To verify. Open up a terminal and type:

```
ps axw | grep postgres
```

If multiple instances of postgres are found. Issue a `kill` command on the respective pid. i.e. `kill 234`